# Require LDAP-based basic authentication for one Apache location and specific group membership for a sub-location

Tags: apache, authentication, ldap, slapd

I have Apache 2.4.7 running on Ubuntu 14. I installed slapd and created two people, `uid=wilma,ou=People,dc=mysite,dc=com` and `uid=betty,ou=People,dc=mysite,dc=com`. They both have object classes `inetOrgPerson`, `posixAccount`, and `shadowAccount`. (I would ultimately like to use the LDAP UID and password for single login.) I have LDAP-based authentication working so that only LDAP-authenticated users can access `/`. This authentication on `/` is only until the site goes live. However, I have an application that I want to permanently use LDAP-based authentication for with location `/my-app`, and I want to limit access to that application to a specific group of people. I created a POSIX group in LDAP called `my-app-users`. I added `uid=wilma,ou=People,dc=mysite,dc=com` to that group.

Disclaimer: I am not highly experience with Apache and brand new to LDAP. I'm not committed to using a POSIX group if that's wrong. (I did pick that object type because I think this group might need to SSH into the server once in a while. Again, brand new!)

The problem is that LDAP authentication is letting both Wilma and Betty into `/my-app`, but I just want Wilma because of her membership in `my-app-users`.

I've tried putting a few variations of this in different places.

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "Access to My App is Restricted"
AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser on
AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern (.*) uid=$1,ou=people,dc=mysite,dc=com
AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost/DC=myside,DC=com?uid
require valid-user
Require ldap-group cn=super-my-app-users,ou=Groups,dc=mysite,dc=com
```

Here:

```
# my-app.conf for my app.
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /my-app /usr/share/my-app/htdocs
</IfModule>

# default.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Location /my-app>
        # Here
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then here (after removing it from the previous place):

```
<Directory /usr/share/my-app/htdocs/>
    # Here
</Directory>
```

I've done a bunch of web searches to figure this out, but I keep ending up with both users getting in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the 2 require directives.  Your users will get in if they are a "valid-user" before the group check.  Remove the first one.

Comment: Rick -- Sorry it took me so long to accept this answer. This got put on the back burner and I didn't have a chance to get to it. Cheers!